# what's the best practice of app pagination in RxJava way?

Tags: android, pagination, rx-java2

Say we got a pagination API `Single<List<Foo>> getFoos(pageToken: String?)` and use RxBinding to watch RecyclerView scroll events `RxRecyclerView.scrollEvents(recyclerView)`.
As far as I can imagine is to implement an operator that convert scroll event to pageToken. In this way, the scroll events flowable depend on the result of API. Should I implement this in a recursive way or is there any elegant way?

Comment: Can you put up some example code, or at least, pseudo-code? That way we might be able to answer. Personally, I cannot think of a recursive way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pagination with rxJava it is no necessary to use rxBinding
You can to make rxjava pagination yourself:

```
 private Observable<Integer> getScrollObservable(RecyclerView recyclerView, int limit, int emptyListCount) {
        return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener sl = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                        int position = getLastVisibleItemPosition(recyclerView);
                        int updatePosition = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1 - (limit / 2);
                        if (position >= updatePosition) {
                            int offset = emptyListCountPlusToOffset ? recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() : recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - emptyListCount;
                            subscriber.onNext(offset);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(sl);
            subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(sl)));
            if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() == emptyListCount) {
                int offset = emptyListCountPlusToOffset ? recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() : recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - emptyListCount;
                subscriber.onNext(offset);
            }
        });
    }
```

see full [example](https://github.com/matzuk/PaginationSample)